# Unable to install MongoDB 4.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I am following this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-tarball/) to install `MongoDB 4.4` on Ubuntu `18.04 LTS` but MongoDB service is not running

```
$ sudo service mongodb status
Unit mongodb.service could not be found.
```

Following commands are used during installation

```
# Install Prerequisites
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4 openssl liblzma5

# Extract the files from the archive
# Binary located at path: /home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/MongoDB/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.4.8.tgz
$ tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.4.8.tgz

# Create the data and log directories
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/mongo
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb

# Give read and write permission
$ sudo chown atinesh /var/lib/mongo
$ sudo chown atinesh /var/log/mongodb

# Add MongoDB installation path to ~/.bashrc
export PATH="/home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/MongoDB/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.4.8/bin:$PATH"  

# Run MongoDB
$ mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 15320
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

Complete log file [mongod.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/whtjdnykih5lcv2/mongod.log?dl=0)

Comment: How is this related to python?

Comment: Btw. I think mongodb is going through some issues with the linux package managers since they have changed their licence. My solution will be to install mongodb as a docker image.

Comment: @mama MongoDB with Docker installation is only available for `MongoDB Enterprise Edition` I need to install `MongoDB Community Edition`

Comment: ok I didnt know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command was producing error because Mongod is running in a daemon mode but installation was successful and I could access MongoDB

```
$ sudo service mongodb status
Unit mongodb.service could not be found.
```